# save function raising error in django tests.py

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, save, django-testing

my model.py is:

```
Sample(models.Model):
   id=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0, primary_key=True)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   length=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0)
   def save(self):
      super(Sample,self).save()
```

in my tests.py:

```
class SampleTestCase(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
self.sample=Sample.objects.create(id=12,name='xyz', length=33)
print self.sample.length
print "hello in setup"
```

my question is when i am using forms or using admin the data is successfully saved without any error but when i am trying to test it it raise error:

```
self.sample=Sample.objects.create(id='12',name='iftikhar', length=33)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 149, in create
return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 414, in create
obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

can any one tell me why this happening here
if i am deleting the save function from models.py the test is running successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overridden the `save` method to take no args.

Try:

```
def save(self, *args, **kw):
      super(Sample,self).save(*args, **kw)
```

Or, just omit this overriding method altogether. It's not doing anything.